# How to Use asopse for Word documents on the.net Core platform

Tags: .net, aspose

Aspose.Word 有没有类似 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word  上下移动光标的方法，或者API?

Comment: I think you will have to translate this to English. It is not clear what you are asking after Google Translate gets done with it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Aspose.Words in .NET Standards (.NET Core etc) platform to detect current cursor position in Word document, move cursor to any Node (*such as Paragraph, Document Start/End, Section, Header/Footer, Table Cell etc*) and then insert new document elements at that position. Please refer to the following article for more details:

[Using DocumentBuilder to Modify a Document Easily](https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsnet/Using+DocumentBuilder+to+Modify+a+Document+Easily)

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist